# Source that King/Beis Din would hang couples for being publicly intimate

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tznius-modesty, beit-din-court, capital-punishment

The title says it all, for the most part, but I remember once hearing that, if it was deemed a common problem, the Beis Din was allowed to round up couples for being publicly intimate, and hang them. (This ability of Beis Din would apply to, I believe, any violation of halacha that they deemed to be a widespread problem.)

Comment: You should see ShA CM 2.

Comment: @DoubleAA Ideally, I would like a Gemara, as that is where I heard it quoted from.

Comment: Shimon ben Shetach hung 80 witches in Ashkelon. See [pcoz's answers](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67992/501) - all other cases in the Talmud they only get lashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very strange, the [gemara says](http://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.90b.18) they gave malkos to a man for being intimate with his wife publicly, and that this was because people were parutz in this ve'haysa ha'shaah tzerichah le'kach, but that seems to be about it.

Comment: Where does the gemara say that?

Comment: וְיֵשׁ גַּם כֵּן רְשׁוּת לְבֵית דִּין לַעֲנֹשׁ וּלְהַכּוֹת כְּפִי צֹרֶךְ הַזְּמָן, אִם יִרְאוּ  שֶׁהַשָּׁעָה צְרִיכָה לְכָךְ, כִּדְגַרְסִינָן בְּמַסֶּכֶת סַנְהֶדְרִין, פֶּרֶק נִגְמַר הַדִּין (מו, א), וּבְמַסֶּכֶת יְבָמוֹת, פֶּרֶק הָאִשָּׁה קַמָּא (צ, ב): תַּנְיָא, אָמַר רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר בֶּן יַעֲקֹב: שָׁמַעְתִּי שֶׁבֵּית דִּין מַכִּין וְעוֹנְשִׁין שֶׁלֹּא מִן הַתּוֹרָה וְלֹא לַעֲבוֹר עַל דִּבְרֵי תוֹרָה אֶלָּא כְּדֵי לַעֲשׂוֹת סְיָג לַתּוֹרָה.

Comment: מַעֲשֶׂה בְּאֶחָד שֶׁרָכַב עַל סוּס בְּשַׁבָּת, בִּימֵי יְוָנִים, וְהֱבִיאוּהוּ לְבֵית דִּין וּסְקָלוּהוּ וְלֹא מִפְּנֵי שֶׁרָאוּי לְכָךְ אֶלָּא  שֶׁהַשָּׁעָה צְרִיכָה לְכָךְ. וְשׁוּב מַעֲשֶׂה בְּאֶחָד שֶׁהִטִּיחַ בְּאִשְׁתּוֹ תַּחַת הַתְּאֵנָה וֶהֱבִיאוּהוּ לְבֵית דִּין וְהִלְקוּהוּ וְלֹא מִפְּנֵי שֶׁרָאוּי לְכָךְ אֶלָּא שֶׁהַשָּׁעָה צְרִיכָה לְכָךְ

Comment: @DannySchoemann If we can get those sources into an answer, I think they were what I was looking for.

Comment: That's what this answer did already.

Comment: @DannySchoemann What is the source for that second Gemara under the tree?

Comment: It's the same Gemarot: בְּמַסֶּכֶת סַנְהֶדְרִין, פֶּרֶק נִגְמַר הַדִּין (מו, א), וּבְמַסֶּכֶת יְבָמוֹת, פֶּרֶק הָאִשָּׁה קַמָּא (צ, ב) - it was just too long for one comment.